# Lifetime of struct with field of type Boxed async callback must outlive 'static

Tags: asynchronous, rust, callback, lifetime, rust-tokio

I have this minimal example:

```rust
use std::{future::Future, pin::Pin, thread::JoinHandle, fmt::Debug};

use tokio::runtime::Runtime;

struct Callback<E> {
    f: Box<dyn Fn() -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<(), E>> + Send + Sync>> + Send + Sync>,
}

trait Provider {
    fn setup(&self) -> JoinHandle<()>;
}

enum Foo {
    A,
    B
}

trait IntoFoo {
    fn into_foo(&self) -> Foo;
}

impl<E: Debug + IntoFoo> Provider for Callback<E> {
    fn setup(&self) -> JoinHandle<()> {
        std::thread::spawn(move || {
            // Running async function sycnhronously within another thread.
            let rt = Runtime::new().unwrap();
            rt.block_on(handle(Box::new(move || (self.f)())))
              .expect("request loop failed")
          })
    }
}

async fn handle<E: Debug + IntoFoo + 'static>( callback_fn: Box<dyn Fn() -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<(), E>> + Send + Sync>> + Send + Sync>) -> Result<(), E> {
    perform(Box::new(move || (callback_fn)())).await
}

pub async fn perform<
  E: Debug + IntoFoo>(
  op: Box<dyn Fn() -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<(), E>> + Send + Sync>> + Send + Sync>,
) -> Result<(), E> {
    (op)().await
}
```

This is a dumbed down version of some real code where I essentially have to pass around an async callback, inside a struct. This callback is passed through multiple functions. One of them calls the function in a newly spawned thread.

The error I get is inside the thread spawning code, when `handle` is called.

The error is:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/indexer/callback.rs:41:41
   |
27 |   fn bootstrap(&self, input: StageReceiver) -> BootstrapResult {
   |                - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
41 |         rt.block_on(handle_event(input, Box::new(move |ev: &Event| (self.f)(ev)), &retry_policy, utils))
   |                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cast requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`
```

How should I orchestrate this? Open to changing the struct field type and anything similar. I must note however: this function must be able to be called multiple times (it might be inside a loop in `handle`).

A few other threads suggested async callbacks to be passed in a Box, and their results be a pinned boxed trait object. Which is why I tried this system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a non-`'static` `&self` reference in a new thread.

One option would be to use `Arc` instead of `Box`, and clone it:

```rust
use std::{fmt::Debug, future::Future, pin::Pin, sync::Arc, thread::JoinHandle};

use tokio::runtime::Runtime;

struct Callback<E> {
    f: Arc<dyn Fn() -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<(), E>> + Send + Sync>> + Send + Sync>,
}

trait Provider {
    fn setup(&self) -> JoinHandle<()>;
}

enum Foo {
    A,
    B,
}

trait IntoFoo {
    fn into_foo(&self) -> Foo;
}

impl<E: Debug + IntoFoo + 'static> Provider for Callback<E> {
    fn setup(&self) -> JoinHandle<()> {
        let f = Arc::clone(&self.f);
        std::thread::spawn(move || {
            // Running async function sycnhronously within another thread.
            let rt = Runtime::new().unwrap();
            rt.block_on(handle(f)).expect("request loop failed")
        })
    }
}

async fn handle<E: Debug + IntoFoo + 'static>(
    callback_fn: Arc<
        dyn Fn() -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<(), E>> + Send + Sync>> + Send + Sync,
    >,
) -> Result<(), E> {
    perform(callback_fn).await
}

pub async fn perform<E: Debug + IntoFoo>(
    op: Arc<dyn Fn() -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<(), E>> + Send + Sync>> + Send + Sync>,
) -> Result<(), E> {
    op().await
}
```

You can use `Arc` in less places and use `Box` instead (if you have an existing API that you need to use) by wrapping the callback in its own function and box that.

Comment: Could you elaborate slightly on the second alternative you proposed? i.e wrapping callback in own function. What would the type look like?

Comment: @Chase The type will still be `Arc<dyn Fn>`, but e.g. in `handle()` and `perform()` you will take `Box<dyn Fn>`.